# ios correct way to implement like button

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

i'm writing an apps with some facebook actions. I'm using Open Graph. I'm wondering what's the correct way to implement like button. FacebookSDK has some custom views like "FBLikeBoxView", "FBLikeButton", etc but how to use it correctly? I was looking at docs but didn't find anything useful. The things I'd like to "like" are not fb pages or profiles. These are articles which are updating all the time. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (thanks to Sandy Chapman):
[FBLoginControl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLikeControl/)

[Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's what you want to use...](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLikeControl/)

[... and here's some documentation for how to use it.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/)

Not positive if the "Pre-release" notice should apply since the Like Control exists in the current API.

Comment: This is exaclty what i was looking for. Thank u :) I'll edit my post for further anwser-miners.